# Nova launcher new app to homescreen

Tags: stock-android, nova-launcher

How do I specify to which home screen I want Nova to add my new apps to, it worked perfectly some time ago, but not anymore. Now it adds new apps to firs homescreen instead of second. Please help

Comment: I believed it instead added apps on the screen that had space.  If the home screen was full then it would add the apps to the next and like so.

Comment: It does have enough space but I want them to go onto the second page instead of the first